# Magento 2.4.3: Zend removed?

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, magento2.4.3, laminas

Has Zend been finally depreciated?

I'm having issues on Catalog page using an Amasty plugin:

```
Error: Class 'Zend\Serializer\Serializer' not found in /var/www/php/vendor/amasty/shopby-seo/Helper/Data.php:199
```

Is there no backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Magento removed some `laminas` packages.
You can see the difference between the [2.4.2 version](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.2/composer.json) of the `composer.json` and the [2.4.3 one](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3/composer.json).

Not sure why they did it tho.

You can fix this by adding the package in your own `composer.json`, as you did (`composer require ...`).

---

### Another way

---

- without need of `laminas-log` you can perform to create custom log
  file in `Magneto 2.4.3`, write down the following code into your
  file....
- if like have a one **controller** and write down below code into the execute method.

```
 *below code in my Controller file*

  public function execute()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Your Message");

    }
```

Answer (score 12):

I guess I was missing **laminas/laminas-serializer**?

I ran:

```
composer require laminas/laminas-serializer --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/generation var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:flush
```

And the issue was resolved.

Why didn't the **laminas-serializer** install during the upgrade, I'm still confused.

UPDATE:

looks like [laminas-serializer](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-serializer)(security only updates) has been replaced by [jms/serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer)

laminas-serializer seems to work and is backward compatible with Zend packages, but jms/serializer is not compatible with Zend.

Now, I just have to learn how to use it :)

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Absolute legend, I've been banging my head against the wall all morning after eventually managing to upgrade to 2.4.3, and then this happens. Why remove something essential without a compatible replacement?

Comment: Well they do have a replacement, just no information on how to use it or what to replace it with. This change was submarined in 2.4.3 without any notice in the release logs. I call this an "Adobe Effect" - any software that company touches that is not Photoshop / Illustrator is complete trash. I mean honestly - not one release since Magento 1 has been without serious issues. Wait until you figure out that if you turn off Checkout captcha, the checkout doesn't work ;) https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/33200

Comment: In all fairness code should not be directly calling a concrete 
implementation for serialisation. You should be injecting `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface` and using what is provided for that interface.

Answer (score 0):

- without need of `lamicans-log` you can perform to create custom log
  file in `Magneto 2.4.3`, write down the following code into your
  file....
- if like have a one **controller** and write down below code into the execute method.

```
 *below code in my Controller file*

  public function execute()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("Your Message");

    }
```